# How share variables to the threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, shared-state

My program will use threads, but some variables like a collection of links/pages, information about queries (if is updating or none) and some others informations(boolean fields, int fields, etc.) must be shared by the threads.

In this case, all the threads will be processing the same work, but in diferrente elements of a collection.

I want to know if there is a way to do this that don't be create a class/object only to hold these shared data.

**My situation:** I have a lot of pages in the database that will need to be processed, and I cant recover all in one time. In each thread, I have a boolean field to inform if the list of pages is being updated with links from database or not. Each thread has a collection with the pages to process.

In a past programa, I had similar situation. To solve it, I create a Master that hold these states and Slaves that get the infos from the Master. But now I want to do without the Master, work only with the Slaves, but I need to know if there is a way to have only one variable for all threads.

**Example:** if thread1 update some boolean to true, automatically, all the another threads have this boolean as true.

Comment: You don't need to create an object just to hold this data. You need objects themselves.  Can you give an example of what your problem is?

Comment: Ok, I wll add in the question.

Comment: You appear to jump between a problem and solution.  I don't see how the problem to solve relates to the solution.  Can you details what your problem is in more detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to share data between threads you need to make sure it is shared in a *synchronized* fashion, i.e., that the data structures are thread safe.

Have a look at the `java.util.concurrent` package. You could perhaps for instance make use of one of the `BlockingQueue` implementations (`ArrayBlockingQueue`, `DelayQueue`, `LinkedBlockingDeque`, `LinkedBlockingQueue`, `PriorityBlockingQueue`, `SynchronousQueue`).

---

Regarding your comment: Have a look also at the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package. There you'll find classes such as `AtomicBoolean`, `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicReference` and so on.

---

> ***Example: if thread1 update some boolean to true, automatically, all the another threads have this boolean as true.***

I'd suggest you use an `AtomicBoolean` in such case. You *could* presumably also use an ordinary `boolean` as long as you declare it `volatile` (if you don't need compare-and-set operations etc that is).

Comment: I don't need only a collection for concurrent access, but for example, I need to share a boolean field to all threads. How I do this?

Comment: Use `AtomicBoolean` in that case. (Updated my answer.)

Comment: Depending on what you are doing a `boolean` might be all you need. It depends on your requirements as what objects/structures you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. This pattern allows you to schedule a number of concurrent tasks without creating too many tasks at once.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
while(isMoreWork()) {
    while(tpe.getQueue().size() > 10) {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }
    final String link = 
    tpe.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            processLink(link);
        }
    });
}
```